# PHP 7.2.7 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, php-7.2

Getting a warning message with PHP 7.2.7, but with PHP 7.2.11 it works fine.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
foreach ($result->data as $posty) {
```

Any idea? It was working fine with PHP 5.2 too.

Comment: $result is not a object maybe boolean, $result->data is not an array, try dump the variables and post here the values.

Comment: There's no reason to blame individual code failures on specific interpreter versions (or patch levels even), unless sufficient research and debugging indicate so.

Comment: Better than dumping, start the debugger and step through your code.

Comment: @JorgeAugustoMorêradeMoura: 

var_dump($posty);
object(stdClass)#3681 (2) {
  ["next_max_id"]=>
  string(30) "xxxxx_xxxx"
  ["next_url"]=>
  string(170) "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxx/media/recent?access_token=xxx&count=18&max_id=xxx"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thing is changed in php7. Please check if you pass valid array or object to the foreach loop.

The error you are experiencing means that the php interpreter can't cycle through items of your $result->data.

I usually check structures before passing them to foreach like this:

```
if ($result->data && (gettype($result->data)=='array' || gettype($result->data )=='object')) {
 foreach ($result->data as $posty) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure bud. :)

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. OPs problem is not the foreach, it's whatever code produces the data. You should essentially never be writing this kind of type check.